# Assembly "dec" instruction for XMM

Tags: assembly, masm, sse2, sse

I'm currently passing a an external parameter from C to ASM using the following:

```
myFunction proc myVar:qword
    public myFunction

    movdqu xmm3,oword ptr myVar
myFunction endp
```

Ultimately, I want to something similar to the below but first need to determine how to decrease myVar by 1 before I can unpack and interleave the variable so that it is correct for use after being passed. I'm unable to think of the proper way to decrease/subtract the XMMs to make this work.

```
dec myVar
movd xmm3, myVar
punpcklbw xmm3, xmm3
punpcklwd xmm3, xmm3
punpckldq xmm3, xmm3
punpcklqdq xmm3, xmm3
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple subtract by one operation anytime in the above code, i.e.

```
.data
  ddqONE dd 01010101h,01010101h,01010101h,01010101h
.code
...
movd xmm3, myVar
punpcklbw xmm3, xmm3
punpcklwd xmm3, xmm3
punpckldq xmm3, xmm3
punpcklqdq xmm3, xmm3
psubb xmm3, oword ptr [ddqONE]   ; the DEC operation on byte values
```

Another possible problem I noticed in your code:

```
myFunction proc myVar:qword       ; passing 64 bit var on the stack
  public myFunction

  movdqu xmm3,oword ptr myVar     ; referencing it as 128 bit var!!!
myFunction endp
```

As you merely use 'myVar' for byte values, it would be cleaner to pass it like this (or pass it as dword, depending on 32 bit or 64 bit target platform):

```
myFunction proc myVar:qword     ; 64 bit
  public myFunction

  movq xmm3, qword ptr myVar    ; 64 bit
myFunction endp
```

Comment: Determined that the qword could actually be a dword and that `dec myVar` was valid afterwards. This post did actually make me reconsider the bits I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
movd xmm3, myVar
pcmpeqb xmm4, xmm4 ; xmm4 = -1
pxor xmm5, xmm5 ; xmm5 = 0
pshufb xmm3, xmm5
paddb xmm3, xmm4
```